# How vulnerable are password managers in the real world?

Tags: passwords, password-management

I'm a senior undergraduate majoring in computer science. I recently took a computer security class where instead of exams we had a final project that could be anything related to computer security.
So for our project, we designed a cloud based password manager that works on almost every existing site with the key idea being that the credentials are never sent to/stored on the client computer that is trying to login to a website.

While I'd really appreciate feedback on our project, I have a feeling that's not really what Stack Exchange is for, so instead I wanted to ask about the vulnerabilities existing password managers still have.

While they encrypt data when it is stored, when trying to log in to a website, what are the safeguards in place that would stop a malicious extension from just doing something like: `document.getElementById("pass").value` right after the extension is used? What about key loggers recording the master password for the password manager?
Additionally, I've read a couple of academic papers exploiting bugs in password managers where for example the master password is left in unprotected memory.

The biggest question I have is if these are all really problems that have been exploited in the real world, or if these vulnerabilities take too much finesse to implement/scale up.

Comment: Nothing stops a malicious extension from exfiltrating your password, but that's not a threat password managers are trying to mitigate.

Comment: @MechMK1 but are these threats worth mitigating? Are there other safeguards in place other than the password manager itself (i.e. the browser) that help limit these types of attacks?

Comment: @MechMK1 I guess I'm asking if an alternative to password managers pasting your credential in plain text in fields existed, would it actually be a project worth exploring, or is it such a small issue that even if solved wouldn't be worthwhile

Comment: I use 1password and I would really like to see what malicious users would be able to do with the above mentioned.

Comment: @Leon185 even if you have 2 step verification enabled, you could still have a malicious extension get the value after its been put into the input box (at least as far as I can tell)

Comment: @martinpetrov1568 that's what I thought. There has got to be some way of retrieving the auto fill data somehow.

Comment: You're essentially asking how to safely use a computer infected by malware. You can't.

Comment: A password manager that never sends the password to your computer would mitigate some threats but would create new ones. No tool can stop all threats, so it is important to understand what they are designed to stop, what they can't stop, and which threats are actually worth trying to stop.

Comment: @MechMK1 that's actually exactly what I'm trying to look into, and there's a Stanford grad paper title "Fidelius: Protecting User Secrets from Compromised Browsers" that actually inspired the work on our project. Their threat model is basically assuming the entire computer is compromised and figuring out a way to securely interact with sites. Before reading it I definitely would've agreed with you, so it definitely is a paper I'd recommend